# The angular js won't recognize my app?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here I made an angularjs exercise, using this example [here](https://www.script-tutorials.com/responsive-website-using-angularjs/) . The problem is that even-though I've called the script by `ng-app` and also by `<script>` tag. The compiler doesn't or couldn't find the app. What I've have done wrong?

This is the index.html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Scripting tutorial" />
    <title>Angularjs Responsive Website</title>
    <meta name="description" content="This is a tutorial that I did to learn more about angularjs" />

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">


    <link href="css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="js/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/HomeCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ProjectCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ProjectCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/AboutCtrl.js"></script>




</head>
<body>
    <!--links-->
    <header>
        <div class="wrap">
            <a href="#!"><img class="logo" src="images/sample_seller.gif" /></a>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="workBtn" href="#!/" ng-class="{activeSmall:part == 'projects'}">Our Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a id="privacyBtn" href="#!/privacy" ng-class="{activeSmall:part == 'privacy'}">Privacy &amp; Terms</a></li>
                    <li><a id="aboutBtn" href="#!/about" ng-class="{activeSmall:part == 'about'}">About</a></li>
                    <li style="margin-right:0px"><a id="contactBtn" class="active" href="javascript.void(0)" ng-click="showForm()">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!--contact form-->
    <div class="paddRow contactRow">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="head">Contact Us</div>
            <img class="close" src="images/close-button.jpg" ng-click="closeForm()" />
            <form ng-submit="save()" class="contactForm" name="form" ng-hide="loaded">
                <input class="input" required="required" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" ng-model="message.name" />
                <input class="input email" required="required" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Your Email" ng-model="message.email" />
                <textarea class="textarea" rows="5" required="required" placeholder="Your message" ng-model="message.text"></textarea>
                <button class="btn green">Send Message</button>
            </form>

            <!--contact us form response message-->
            <div ng-show="process" style="text-align:center">
                <img class="loader" src="images/loading.png" />
            </div>
            <div ng-show="success"><p>Your message has been sent, Thank You!</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Main Content-->
    <div style="position:relative">
        <div style="width:100%" ng-view ng-animate="{enter: 'view-enter', leave: 'view-leave'}"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the app.js:-

```
'use strict';

var app = angular
            .module('MyApp',
            [
                'ngRoute'
            ])
            .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/',
                    {
                        templateUrl: 'pages/pro-index.html',
                        controller: HomeCtrl
                    })
                    .when('project/:projectId',
                    {
                        templateUrl: function (params) {
                            return 'pages/' + params.projectId + '.html';
                        },
                        controller: ProjectCtrl,
                        activetab: 'projects'
                    })
                    .when('/privacy',
                    {
                        templateUrl: 'pages/privacy.html',
                        controller: PrivacyCtrl,
                        activetab: 'privacy'
                    })
                    .when('/about',
                    {
                        templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
                        controller: AboutCtrl,
                        activetab: 'about'
                    })
                    .otherwise(
                    {
                        redirectTo: '/'
                    });
            }])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$http', '$browser', '$timeout', '$route', function ($scope, $http, $browser, $timeout, $route) {
        $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (scope, next, current) {
            $scope.part = $route.current.activetab;
        });
        console.log('My app works!');
        //onclick event handlers
        $scope.showForm = function () {
            $('.contactRow').slideToggle();
        };
        $scope.closeForm = function () {
            $('.contactRow').slideUp();
        };

        // save the Contact us form
        $scope.save = function () {
            $scope.loaded = true;
            $scope.process = true;
            $http.post('sendemail.php', $scope.message).success(function () {
                $scope.success = true;
                $scope.process = false;
            });
        };
    }]);

app.config(['$locationProvider', function ($location) {
    $location.hashPrefix('!');
}
]);
```

The error is that it says Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
HomeCtrl is not defined... I've defined it too

Here it is:

```
(function () {

    angular
        .module('MyApp')
        .controller('HomeCtrl', HomeCtrl);
    HomeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function HomeCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.Hello = "Hello";
    };

})();
```

Comment: did you get interrupted when entering the question?  "The error is that the ".... ?  Also, Angular is JavaScript, and JavaScript is run in the browser, there is no compiler.

Comment: Sorry here's the full question.

Comment: where is the controller declared in the HTML?

Comment: you have not included any controller in index.html. After declaring the controller in html define it in the JS file.

Comment: ok, so you are using the angular router, which means that you need a `<ui-view>` for the controller and the template to be bound to, and you would need a *different* controller for any angular bindings that aren't handled by that template.  There is a bit too much going on here to try to fix it all.

Comment: incidentally, the article you are following was written in 2013, and there have been **significant** changes to the operations and syntax of the angular framework.  This would probably work if you matched your angular version exactly to the one that was available at the time of the writing of this article, but I don't recommend learning depreciated syntax.

Comment: oh yes.  that's what i'm afraid. i'm using the latest version. So that's means I've have to change some coding to a later one right? :(

Comment: the way this code is structured is no longer valid with the current stable angular releases.

Comment: Yeah thanks. Even if i copied and paste, it won't (I did to see if i did something wrong) So i better find a another example which is latest and learn from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guys won't believe what I found out. Nobody didn't. My app did work all along. As of new edition of angularjs, My app failed to recognize my controllers is because... wait for it... "SINGLE QUOTES" = `'...'` So you have to name controllers inside single quotes.

> So it would be;

`controller: 'HomeCtrl'`

There you have it. All those who got stuck doing this will now have a feeling to try out.

THANKS FOR THE HELP GUYS!

*Also felt shame of posting this question as well.*

Answer (score 1):

First declare a controller within your angularJS code like so:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.firstName = "John";
 $scope.lastName = "Doe";

$scope.myFunc = function(){

 //YOUR FUNCTION CODE HERE

}
});
```

Put your functions within the controller and assign them to the **$scope** of the controller. And then use **ng-controller** within your HTML like so:

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
  Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

  // RUN FUNCTION LIKE SO
  <button ng-click="myFunc()"></button>
</body>
```

Hope this helps.